# Why #selector function doesn't work if property is not lazy var (and compiler doesn't tell me about it)?

Tags: ios, swift, selector, lazy-evaluation

I create a gesture recognizer property in a class and pass @objc function as an argument.

```
private let tapGestureRecognizer =
    UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: #selector(toggleTapped))

@objc private func toggleTapped() {
    //some actions
}
```

But, toggleTapped() function doesn't get called after gesture recognizer is triggered. 
Only if I change my property declaration to `lazy var` everything seems to be working.

Why compiler doesn't tell me about my mistake? Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I don't consider it a bug because you're not referring to `self` in the property's declaration (which obviously cannot be done before `self` becomes available and thus the need to lazy load instance properties that refer to `self`), the property's initializer is referring to `self` (which is not itself, but the view controller) which is obviously allowable.

Answer (score 1):

Because `let` variables are given a value before `self/super.init` is ran, which means that `self` doesn't exist yet. A `lazy` variable are given a value when needed, and AFTER `init`, which means that `self` does exist. Your gesture references `self`, and thus its creation needs to be postponed until `self` actually exists.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But why compiler is silent about this? If I try to assign non-lazy property with self members, it immediately tells me about this. Why initializing with #selector() is an exception?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't catch it because you are using it as a parameter instead of referencing it directly and the compiler doesn't catch everything.